# Implementing array elements in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I tried to print the array elements in the text box the command is as follows

[image]

while sending the values of vehicles to iterator so that I can further enter the values as `${KEY_ENTER}`with the array elements it does not pass the value of the vehicle to the iterator.

Is there an alternate way where I can send the array values so that I can target `css=.XTCLo` to that array elements.

I even tried by executing

```
type | css=.XTCL0| ${iterator}
```

But it just enters ${iterator} instead rather than value by doing so.

So tried using send keys command but it didn't work can someone help me with this?

```
Output

Running '1st (1)'
15:16:08
1.open on / OK
15:16:09
2.executeScript on ["car","bus"] with value vehicles OK
15:16:09
3.forEach on vehicles with value iterator OK
15:16:11
4.store on myitems with value myvar OK
15:16:11
5.click on css=.Fifk5 .\_6q-tv OK
15:16:11
6.Trying to find vehicles... Failed:
15:16:12
Implicit Wait timed out after 30000ms
Warning implicit locators are deprecated, please change the locator to id=vehicles
15:16:15
```

I think using id=vehicles as per suggestion is meaningless here as per suggestion.
I even tried by entering send keys | `css=.XTCL0|${iterator}` But it just enters `${iterator}` instead rather than value as previous type case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I executed `script | return ["car", "bus"] | vehicles`, then replaced `send keys | vehicles | ${iterator}` with `send keys | css=.XTCL0| ${iterator}` this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the array

[image]

you have add target as `return ["car","bus"]` instead of `["car","bus"]`

and use `for each ${vehicles}    iterator`

In selenium, we use `name` in the value field (to store something to the variable) and `${name}` in target while targeting (when need to access the stored variable)

Now you will have car and bus respectively for each iteration.

**Second issue:**

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands#send-keys

send-keys expect locator in target and what to send to that locator as value.

so,

`send keys     vehicles    ${iterator}`    is the wrong syntax, I am not sure what you are truing to do.

Comment: Initially I did 
send key | css=.XTCLo | ${iterator}
To enter the value of array to CSS class

Comment: Add return to your execute script

Comment: If I echo the array element it works but 
If I want to enter the array element to textbox it doesn't

Comment: you are using wrong locator then , show your dom

Comment: https://send.firefox.com/download/d23574b1c8e6abfe/#DpKzSLHzC8fDfD9uzSrs6g see this, its a selenium IDE program to open google and type inut in it

Comment: Link says expired while
here is my dom error when I try to type the array message in textbox

Trying to find vehicles... Failed:
Implicit Wait timed out after 30000ms
Warning implicit locators are deprecated, please change the locator to id=vehicles

if i use css class instead of vehicles
${iterator} is entered instead of its value

Comment: https://send.firefox.com/download/0ebcd38f571d024e/#Z3kOdH_0ShlUiLtmnBLvSA use this ,